# How to best implement Accelerate for vary large models

Tags: machine-learning, language-model

This was pointed out to me: https://huggingface.co/blog/accelerate-large-models

and seems it could be a great resource, but it is broken down into steps as a tutorial vs as out of the box solution script.

Does anyone know of a good library, or example code that implements Accelerate for large models to use less VRAM / RAM?

This is what I tried to run last:

```
from accelerate import infer_auto_device_map, init_empty_weights

from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig

import torch

checkpoint = "bigscience/mt0-small"

config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

with init_empty_weights():

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_config(config)

device_map = infer_auto_device_map(model, no_split_module_classes=["OPTDecoderLayer"], dtype="float16")

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

device_map["model.decoder.layers.37"] = "disk"

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(

checkpoint, device_map=device_map, offload_folder="offload", offload_state_dict = True, torch_dtype=torch.float16

)
```

Goal is to run **Flan-T5** or **BLOOMZ** locally, using disk space, to run the models on lower resources.

This code throws the error:

```
ValueError: Unrecognized configuration class <class 'transformers.models.mt5.configuration_mt5.MT5Config'> for this kind of AutoModel: AutoModelForCausalLM
```

That is another issue, it would be good to know how to supply a configuration or convert the config to a supported type.
And not sure if the code I put together would work once that is addressed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: hi, do you solved? same problem here, i found another strategy bud did not work for me https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/usage_guides/big_modeling

Comment: Still foggy on this, but thanks for posting the link. It could be pretty useful. These days I would be most likely to use something like GPT4ALL or  oobabooga's webui if possible